# android: WebView, display html content from assets folder

Tags: android, xml, webview

Help me. I was trying to display my html page in android. But it shows error.

My code in xml,

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

As in java;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv;  
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapter1.html");  
}
```

}

But, while run the app... it shows much errors as follows;

```
07-31 11:04:05.056: D/AndroidRuntime(1008): Shutting down VM
07-31 11:04:05.096: W/dalvikvm(1008): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thaufeeq.tamilquran/com.thaufeeq.tamilquran.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at com.thaufeeq.tamilquran.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     ... 11 more
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     ... 23 more
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060001 a=-1 r=0x7f060001}
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
07-31 11:04:05.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1008):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: the problem seems to be in your XML file. Are you trying to set some drawable to your RelativeLAyout that it can not find? Can you post your RelativeLAyout part of the xml? You are getting RelativeLayout and Resource not found errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right. This code works for me when I checked. Better, you again do Debug with this code, by replacing this below code. (NO MORE MODIFICATIONS)

YOUR JAVA FILE:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Webview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapter1.html");  
    }   
}
```

YOUR XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Webview" >

<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/webview">
 </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem so i have copied that file from asset to sdcard.
it solved my problem. 
take a look at AssetManager class once if possible

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);
            File f = new File(Controller.getController()
                    .getApplicationBasePath() + "/Document_Directory");
            if (f.exists()) {
                out = new FileOutputStream(Controller.getController()
                        .getApplicationBasePath()
                        + "/Document_Directory/"
                        + filename);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } else {
                f.mkdir();
                copyAssets();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }
    }
}
```